# How can I change a snippet of rendered HTML in Wordpress's twentyseventeen theme?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, templates, wordpress-theming

Wordpress's twentyseventeen theme, by default, displays a customizable image that is expected to be 2000x1200. [A default image is provided](https://wordpress.org/themes/twentyseventeen/) along with video support, but I would like to display, sans the picture of the gilt frame, a slightly higher-resolution version of [a slideshow](https://cjshayward.com/wp-content/raw/slideshow.html).

I have created a child theme of twentyseventeen for this and other changes, and while I have traipsed through the code of twentyseventeen and Wordpress, I have not succeeded in getting a particular error message to log, nor a `<!-- Reached here! -->` comment to be appended to the output.

The HTML I would like to replace is the IMG tag in:

```
<div class="custom-header-media">
    <div id="wp-custom-header" class="wp-custom-header"><img src="https://cjshayward.com/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/assets/images/header.jpg" width="2000" height="1200" alt="C.J.S. Hayward" /></div>   </div>
```

What I would like to be able to do is replace that IMG tag with custom HTML which I imagine would be edited into [the slideshow](https://cjshayward.com/wp-content/raw/slideshow.html)'s source. In other words, instead of the one IMG tag, I would like two IMG tags with attributes I specify to be placed where the rendered IMG tag is now, and somewhere further down the page (possibly right after), a SCRIPT tag that would run the animating JavaScript.

I suspect some or all of the information I want to replace is drawn from the database; as the admin interface lets you customize which (one) top-of-page image if you're not going the MP4 route, I'm not surprised that the twentyseventeen theme as installed does not contain the string '/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/assets/images/header.jpg' in any of its files.

How can I substitute a (static) text of my choosing where the IMG tag is?

Thanks,

Comment: itsso simple.You haveto override custom_header

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Headers

Comment: @VasimVanzara Please restate one or both comments as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks,